# "dist" command gets "not a valid command" error

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, cloudbees, typesafe-activator

I have a working Play Framework 2.1 application generated with typesafe activator that I've developed in Scala.  I'm trying to deploy it in CloudBees using the instructions that can be found here: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework#HDeployingaPlay2application using the method described under "Using Cloudbees SDK."

However, when I load up the play console and try to run the "dist" command, I get the error "Not a valid command: dist."

I've tried two run this three different ways:

1. In the terminal window (I'm using Mac OS X), I navigated to the project directory, ran the "activator" application (there is no application in that directory called "play", but "activator" seems to be the), then from the prompt that appears I enter the command "dist."
2. I downloaded the regular (non-activator) Play Framework distirbution file, add the directory to my path using "export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/play-2.2.2", navigated to the project directory, and ran the command "play dist."
3. Installed play using Homebrew.  Navigated to the project directory and ran "play dist".

All three methods give me the same error (see below).  Is the method different for my version of play?  Am I missing something from the sbt file?  How can I get this working?

Full output for "play dist":

```
Macmini-##########-#:nimrandslibrary.searchfu.esl kpyancey$ play dist
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/kpyancey/Projects/NimrandsLibrary.SearchFu.Esl/project
[info] Set current project to NimrandsLibrary.SearchFu.Esl (in build file:/Users/kpyancey/Projects/NimrandsLibrary.SearchFu.Esl/)
[error] Not a valid command: dist (similar: set, iflast, last)
[error] Not a valid project ID: dist
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: dist (similar: test, ivy-sbt, history)
[error] dist
[error]     ^
```

Comment: I have installed play on my mac with homebrew, browsed to my app folder and run "play dist" without any problem. Not sure what you mean by "there is no application called play", though.

Comment: If you type `play`, do you arrive at the `play`console?

Comment: yes, if you don't, I guess you did not use homebrew(which already set the PATH for you) and did some mistakes while configuring your PATH

Comment: I didn't know about the Homebrew option.  I know PATH is set correctly, because it DOES run the "play" command and launches the play console.  But, when I type "dist" into play console's prompt, it gives me the error message I mentioned above.  I'll update the question as soon as I've finished the Homebrew install and attempted to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misconfigured something in your project.

To double check, generate a new project from Activator or try downloading https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-clickstart (which is correctly configured) and run play dist.

Comment: I tested it, and "play dist" works in the project generated through ClickStart.  However, this doesn't help me much.  I have a WORKING application already, and integrating the existing codebase into the ClickStart-generated project is less than trivial.  Additionally, the ClickStart-generated project sets up source control to be hosted on Cloudbees (I already have my own source control), and requires me to upload code, and then test by running the application the Cloudbees server (which slows down my code-compile-test cycle greatly).  This is not the setup I want.

Comment: You gave me an idea, though.  I'm creating a new project in Typesafe Activator to see if "play dist" will run for it.  If it does, I can compare the configuration of the two projects.  If not, then we'll have narrowed down the problem, at least.  I'll update when I know more.

Comment: I generated a new project from Activator and the "play dist" command works for it.  I still have no idea what the could have been different with the project configuration that would cause "play dist" to fail like that (i.e., to not even recognize the "dist" command).  I updated your answer to reflect the fact that I created a new project through activator to resolve the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have found the same behaviour with `play-intro-java` application as part of Play tutorials. As I was experimenting around, I accidentally removed the tests from the default `test/` folder. Trying to run `activator clean dist` failed with the message above which is totally unexpected considering the root cause (missing tests). Perhaps someone will find this info useful.